# Как сделать рп команды боту телеграмм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пытаюсь сделать рп команду телеграмм боту (пример который хочу воплотить - https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL5uQ.png). Да код взял из инета, но даже там не сработало. Работает на меня. Прошу помогите!!

```
def obn(message):
        user_name = message.from_user.first_name
        user_nametwo = message.from_user.first_name
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {user_name} обнял {user_nametwo}')
```

Comment: вы перехватываете все сообщения и когда текст сообщения соответствует команде - вы запускаете обработчик данной команды. Практически в каждом пакете есть соответствующий хендлер.

Comment: в вашем случае, наверное, это хендлер с регулярным выражением: `@bot.message_handler(regexp="SOME_REGEXP")` в `SOME_REGEXP` нужно будет подставить шаблон сообщения, которое ты хочешь перехватить. и в обработчике выслать то как бот должен на эту команду отреагировать.